# how to use group by with current year months and another data field in sequelize

Tags: sql, node.js, date, group-by, sequelize.js

[related table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9UGS.png)

I need GROUP BY createdAt's month and status in the current year using sequelize.
my expected output is:-
[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsLkn.png)

Answer (score 0):

(might need to adjust syntax according to your db):

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', createdAt) as month,
       status,
       COUNT(id)
FROM table
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

If you really only want the month number use `DATE_PART` instead of `DATE_TRUNC`

Comment: Which dbms is this very product specific answer for?